# Error while trying to create Assets/Asset Volumes

Tags: assets, server, craft4, assets-field, assetfilemodel

If I try to create a asset field, a server error occurs when I select the Field type "Asset" and I can't edit it further.
I also can't edit my Assets because when I click on it I get an exception saying "Volume is missing its filesystem handle", even though I've already created one. The same happens when I try to edit my Asset Fields.
Does anyone know what I should do?
(The 2nd picture is in german) [image][image]

Comment: Can you check that the asset volume(s) selected for this new field are have attached filesystem?